# How to find the name of current JTextField of a View in Java?

Tags: java, jtextfield, focusmanager, keyboardfocusmanager

I have a view in Java where I am entering data in JTextfields. A thread is running in parallel that gets input from a keypad by using snippets of code written below. Now whenever I call

```
JTextField c = (JTextField) manager.getFocusOwner();
c.getText();
```

where the manager is

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentFocusManager();
```

It does return the text of the current JTextField but when I call the following line, it returns null.

```
c.getName();
```

Why is this happening and how should I solve this?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please. Without the instanciation of the component, how could we guess ?

Comment: Ok, sir! My bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set a name for the text field in the first place. You can't .getName if you haven't .setName.

Cheers!

Comment: The JTextField c is just a temporary variable to get the JTextField which has the focus in the view. Do you mean that I have to use setName when creating the JTextField in the view or for the temporary var?

Comment: The actual text field itself must be named with .setName. In this case it would be c.setName("Some Name");

Comment: Wait, strike that, the JTextField that is being focused must be named.

Comment: Lol alright that works too  an upvote or correct answer mark world be appreciated. Trying to build me rep haha

Comment: Yes, I guessed that because obviously the JTextField whose focus we are requesting should set its name. :)